# What information from a class do I pass to get desired results

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on taking a file and putting it into an arraylist. Then using the split method from the String class to make an arraylist with the formatted tokens. In my tester class it lets me put in line or null. Null does nothing and line enters the first token in all three fields. I cant get the while loop to give me the correct info. What should I pass in there to get what I am looking for in my class constructor? Here is my code.

```
public class TriviaGame {
   String category;
   String question;
   String answer;




public TriviaGame(String category, String question, String answer) {
    super();
    this.category = category;
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}





@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TriviaGame [category=" + category + ", question=" + question
            + ", answer=" + answer + "]";
}





/**
 * @return the category
 */
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}





/**
 * @param category the category to set
 */
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}





/**
 * @return the question
 */
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}





/**
 * @param question the question to set
 */
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}





/**
 * @return the answer
 */
public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}





/**
 * @param answer the answer to set
 */
public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}





}
```

then the tester

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TriviaGameTester2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File dataFile = new File ("trivia.txt");

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(dataFile);
        String line;
        String [] words;
        TriviaGame [] games;
        final int NUM_QUESTIONS = 300;
        int counter;
        TriviaGame temp;

        games = new TriviaGame[NUM_QUESTIONS];

        counter = 0;


        while(infile.hasNext()){
            line = infile.nextLine();
            words = line.split("[,]");


            temp = new TriviaGame(null, null, null);
            //what should I put here to get my categories, questions
                            //and answers?
            games[counter] = temp;
            counter++;

        }

        infile.close();

        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            System.out.println(games[i]);
        }


        }



}
```

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: In my gameTester2 class where i have temp =, right now it says null, null, null, eclipse also recommended line. When I use null, I get category = null, question = null, answer = null, when I use line i get category = entertainment, question = entertainment, and answer = entertainment, then the second time it does the question for all, then the answer for all. Im asking what should i have in its place so that I get one category, one question, and one answer

Comment: What format is the file in?

Comment: Sorry, the file is in a text format that I am reading from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines of code depend on the order in which you added the categories, questions and answers to your file. Supposing that each line in your file is: category, question, answer, your code would be:

```
temp.setCategory(words[0]);
temp.setQuestion(words[1]);
temp.setAnswer(words[2]);
```

or, you could just do:

```
temp = new TriviaGame(words[0], words[1], words[2]);
```

Comment: do I use that where I have the null, null, null?

Comment: That would work, yes. temp = new TriviaGame(words[0], words[1], words[2]);

The code I posted initially assumed you wanted to keep the null, null, null. If you don't, this code can completely replace it.

Comment: Awesome, it works. Now I can move on to the real good stuff in it! Thanks